# Capital letters in resume

Tags: capitalization

I'm writing my resume right now and I was wondering what is the correct way to use capital letters in it.

I will give few examples of sentences that I'm not sure whether should be capital or not:

1. John John award of excellence in research: Aircraft Structure Monitoring using Optical Sensors.

Do I need to capitalize each word in the title of the research/ do I need to capitalize the sentence Award of Excellence?

2. Developing in MATLAB and Simulink a full aircraft simulation including guidance, control, and aerodynamics to prove the results.

Do I need to capitalize the words Guidance, Control and Aerodynamics?

Thank you

Comment: In 1) you could make it clear *in that sentence* that is the title of your paper (not the name of the award) and "quote" it. In 2) why do you think those words should be capitalized, and not the other nouns? Only capitalize proper nouns, other you will give the Impression that Everything is important.